# Native scroll delaying or stopping JavaScript execution on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-safari, user-experience

This isn't a specific JS code issue, but more the way iOS deals with JS that is causing more problems on my site than most others.

On iOS only (it doesn't happen on Android) if I'm natively scrolling (up/down) and then try to activate some JS just before the scroll has finished (very quickly) then it completely ignores the JS.

I believe that Apple do this so that the UX always remains priority (don't let any crappy JS slow down the user), but in this case it's just a very simple piece of JS that I want to allow to run.

As an example, if a user is scrolling and then quickly presses a tab at the top of the screen that opens a fixed navigation panel then it won't register if the native scroll is still happening. If they press it again (the scroll has finished) then it works.

I'm also using a JS slider to scroll horizontally through images and if I try to scroll left/right just before the native up/down scroll has finished it sort of jumps and isn't good UX. I think it's prioritising the native scroll but still activating the horizontal scroll with some sort of delay.

It's not a massive problem, but not perfect. If everybody slowly navigated the site and waited for the native scroll to come to a complete stop, it would be great. But of course people won't do this.

I don't think preventing the default behaviour will do anything. I have tried to take over the native scroll before on iOS and I just don't think you can.

I think this may actually happen on many sites. I've just tried to find a good example by visiting stackoverflow.com on an iPhone and if you scroll quickly and then quickly hit a link before the scroll has finished it won't register. I don't think text links are as big a UX issue though, but a horizontal slider and big 'open menu' button at the top are much more likely to be hit quickly before the native scroll has ended (as you don't need to read something before you press it, like with text links).

I have various JS scripts on a site that would benefit from this being improved in iOS, so if I can understand a way around it, why it happens, what is going on, then I can apply individual fixes to each of those scripts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not that iOS ignores javascript while scrolling (more precisely, while the scroll momentum is active). The problem is that, while that happens, iOS does not really register the position change of elements on the screen. In fact, if you have a handler attached to the `scroll` event, it will stop firing the moment you stop touching the screen, and then will fire just once when the scrolling stops.

Consequence? You think you're touching a link, but you aren't. The image on the screen has moved up or down, but, to the broswer, everything is on the same position, so, actually, you aren't touching anything (or are touching something different). I got very annoyed when I found this behaviour because, in my case, my page is full of images that are links to a gallery ... and if you touch them while scrolling, the gallery opens showing you not the image you touched, but another (The one that really was on that position when your fingers stopped touching the screen).

Is there a workaround? The only one that I know of is disabling the scroll momentum, but you lose scrolling performance.